# using SUBSTR to separate value in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, substr

I have a column (call it column1 here) in my database with data formatted like this: "x/y/z". I want to create a new column with just the x value and I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE RECORDS
ADD COLUMN name_x TEXT;
SELECT column1, SUBSTR('column1','/',1) AS new_column FROM table;
```

The new column does not contain any data, while I expected x for each row.

[image: code and table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd argument of the function [`SUBSTR()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) is the starting position of the substring that you want to return (in this case it is 1) and the 3d argument is the number of characters returned.
So for the 2nd argument you must use the function [`INSTR()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) to locate the `'/'`:

```
SUBSTR(course_id, 1, INSTR(course_id, '/') - 1)
```

If you have already created the new column `institution` then you must update the table to populate the new column:

```
UPDATE records
SET institution = SUBSTR(course_id, 1, INSTR(course_id, '/') - 1)
```

If your version of SQLite is 3.31+ you could create the new column as a [generated column](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/gencol.html) like this:

```
ALTER TABLE records ADD COLUMN institution TEXT 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTR(course_id, 1, INSTR(course_id, '/') - 1));
```